# Splunk csv to match country code

Tags: match, prefix, phone-number, splunk

I'm using splunk but having trouble trying to match first 2 or 3 digits in this:

sample:
messageId=9492947, to=61410428007

My csv looks like this:

```
to, Country   
93, Afghanistan  
355, Albania  
213, Algeria  
61, Australia
```

I'm trying to push the fields into a CSV and tell me what Country they matched.

I think I need to be doing a regex or something, but i have interesting fields marked in splunk which is "to"

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those messy ones, but it does not require regular expressions.  Let's say you have a CSV file with a header - something like:

```
code,country
92,Afghanistan
355,Albania
214,Algeria
61,Australia
44,United Kingdom
1,United States
```

You need the header for this.  I created an example file, but the source can come from anywhere just as long as you have the to field extracted properly.

```
source="/opt/testfiles/test-country-code.log" 
| eval lOne=substr(to,1,1) 
| eval lTwo=substr(to,1,2) 
| eval lThree=substr(to,1,3) 
| lookup countries.csv code as lOne OUTPUT country as cOne 
| lookup countries.csv code as lTwo OUTPUT country as cTwo 
| lookup countries.csv code as lThree OUTPUT country as cThree 
| eval country=coalesce(cOne,cTwo,cThree) 
| table to,country
```

The substr calls extract one, two or three characters from the start of the string.  The lookups convert each of those variables to the country name using the lookup table.  The coalesce will take the first one of those with a value.